# How do you find the number of digits for a solution for logarithmic equation and inequalities?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

In this question using the laws of logarithms to solve the equation and inequality you're **not supposed to use a calculator**:

You are given that log₁₀ 4 = 0.60206 correct to 5 decimal places and that 10 (to the power of 0.206) < 2.

a) Find the number of digits in the number 4¹⁰⁰.

b) Find the first digit in the number 4¹⁰⁰.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what the laws of logarithms say about $\log 4^{100}$?

Answer (score 2):

The logarithm base $10$ of $4^{100}$ is $60.2...$,

so $4^{100}=10^{0.2...}\times10^{60}$,

i.e., $1\times10^{60}<4^{100}<2\times10^{60}$,

so $4^{100}$ has $61$ digits, and the first digit is $1$.

Comment: How did you get that inequality form the equation? Also, how do you know that it is 61 digits and that the first digit is 1?

Comment: because $1<10^{0.2...}<2$.  May help you to consider if $1\times10^2<x<2\times10^2$ then $x$ has $3$ digits and its first digit is $1$

Comment: ok, i understand now. Thank you so much for your help.